# Smallest number $N$ for a prime $p$ such that there are primes of the form $kp+a < N$ for all $\in \{1,2 \dots p-1\}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Whats the smallest number $N$ where for a prime $p$ there are primes $p_a$ where $p_a = kp+a < N$ for all a $\in \{1,2 \dots p-1\}$

For example for $p = 13$, $p_1 = 53, p_2 = 41, p_3 = 3, p_4 = 17, p_5 = 5, p_6 = 19,p_7 = 7, p_8 = 47, p_9 = 61, p_{10} = 23, p_{11} = 11, p_{12} = 103$

In this case $N = 104$

I plotted out these values and this is what I got. Are there any bounds that can be placed here?

[image: p vs N]

Comment: Siegel Walfisz theorem gives $\log (N)\ll p^\epsilon$. Here are some explicit constants for $p^{0.5+\epsilon}$: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: Wikipedia's [Linnik's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnik%27s_theorem) article states the bound $\operatorname{p}(a,d)\leq \varphi(d)^{2}(\log d)^{2}$ has been "[proven](https://doi.org/10.1090%2FS0025-5718-2015-02925-1)" (but based on the GRH being true), where the $d$ there is your prime $p$, so we get $N \le \varphi(p)^{2}(\log p)^{2} + 1$. Note this is the best, as far as that article states, proven bound, but it's been conjectured that $\operatorname{p}(a,d)\lt d^{2}$.

Comment: @John linnik theorem just gives a polynomial bound - the result you mention is proven only on GRH; as of now the power seems to be at most $5$

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for the clarification. I misread what was read there initially, so I've updated my comment to try to make it more clear that the result is only proven conditionally on GRH being true.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I'm a little confused, Linnik's Theorem is about primes in an arithmetic progression and I'm not sure how it's being applied here.

Comment: Note that if you consider the minimum prime $p_a$ where there's a positive integer $k$ with $p_a=kp+a$, then we have the smallest $N$ meeting your requirements being $N=\max(p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_{p-1})+1$.  This $\max$ value is what Linnik's theorem deals with. However, since you don't specifically require $k$ to be positive, then for primes $a$ we could use $k=0$, so the minimum value of $N$ could possibly be a bit smaller. Finally, FYI, a site search of [Linnik's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Linnik%27s+theorem) currently shows $28$ results, so some may be of interest to you.